# What is issue with following code on iphone browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I have used jQueryCollapse plugin for displaying Questions and Answers.
Question is written on Tab and Answer is displayed when we click on tab.
When tab is active means when answer is displayed at that time page height increases and because of that I have to increase the height of background image.
For that I have coded as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-content1').height(1450);
    $("#t1").click(function(){
        var height = 1450;
        $('#main-content1').height(height);
    });
    $("#t2").click(function(){
        var height = 1450;
        $('#main-content1').height(height);
    });
    $("#t3").click(function(){
        var height = 1275;
        $('#main-content1').height(height);
    });
    $("#t4").click(function(){
        var height = 1250;
        $('#main-content1').height(height);
    });
</script>
```

The CSS code for id main-content is as follows:

```
#main-content1 {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:35px;
    width:900px;

    border-top-left-radius:48px;
    border-top-right-radius:48px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:48px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:48px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:1450px;
    background:url(res/back-img.png) repeat;
}
```

The code for footer is as follows:

```
#footer {
    border-top: 0px solid #003366;
    overflow:visible;
}

.foot {
    float:left; 
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    background-image:url(res/footer_back.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:visible;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background-position:0px 120px;
    width:182px;
    height:180px;
}

img {
    border-color:transparent;   
}

#site-footer {
    width:728px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

When I click on tab it shows answer but not increasing its background image height as per jquery code on iphone mobile browser. But it is working fine on windows pc browser.
The content is going behind the footer.
I did Google very much but I am not getting how to resolve this issue.
Please can any one help me out to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Add you `footer` css as well

Comment: This seems a structural issue? needed your css.

Comment: @Morpheus: I have added footer css code also..

Comment: Is that line `width:900px;*/` just typo?

Comment: It might be worth adding a note about the specific browser versions you're using. Which iOS version are you using? And which PC browser/version? And have you tried any other PC (or mobile) browsers?

Comment: @Morpheus: its jst typo..

Comment: @Spudley: I am using Windows 7, it works fine here, and also works fine on samsung mobile browser, but having problems on iphone mobile safari browsers..

Comment: @AnandJaju - uh, so what I mean is, is it IE9 on Win7 or IE10? (or even IE8?). Or maybe it's Chrome or Firefox or....??? And if it is IE, have you confirmed that it isn't in quirks mode or compatibility mode? (which would cause it to render incorrectly compared with other browsers)

Comment: Also, have you tried using the `background-size` CSS property?

Comment: @Spudley: I am using firefox and chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test yet, but try max-height instead of height/ or auto height.

## CSS

```
#main-content1 {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:35px;
    width:900px;

    border-top-left-radius:48px;
    border-top-right-radius:48px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:48px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:48px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    max-height:1450px; /* height:auto; */
    background:url(res/back-img.png) repeat;
}
```